# Is there a way of dynamically resizing video / images with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, video, resize

This one was bothering me for a long time and still, I cannot find the solution.

Does anyone know how to dynamically resize the dimensions of the video (embedded from say youtube / vimeo etc.) and images in the mobile version of the website, developed with jQuery Mobile.

My scenario is that the mobile version of the website pulls the content from the same database / table as the main website, where images and videos are much larger than they should be for the handheld device. Any tips?

Comment: To do real resizing (not scaling) you'll need a server side solution.

Comment: Images aren't really massive and since they are within the content of the page it would be rather unnecessary to create two copies of the same content just to display a different variation with the smaller image on the mobile device - especially that mobile devices have different dimensions and you can preview the page either horizontally or vertically, which should also resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

Dont mix images and video resize problem.
Image resize is recommended do on server side (PHP/Python,C# etc) for smaller traffic and faster load mobile site.
Video can be resized with FFMpeg on server side, if video from external hosting (like youtube), then start play with lowest quality.

Comment: Does FFMpeg deal with youtube / vimeo / blip etc - embeded code?

Comment: I recommend you don't convert video from video hostings due to high traffic for your site. If this not problem, then try learn about ffserver (part of FFMpeg).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function:

```
/**
 * resize_embedded resizes embedded videos like youtube videos;
 * Examples: 
 *  - resize_embedded($('youtube_div'), 300, 200);
 *  - Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjxVC/1
 *
 * Parameters:
 * @param jquery the element that contains the embedded media
 * @param number the new width
 * @param number the new height
 *
 */
function resize_embedded(){

    // Did we receive 3 correct parameters
    if(arguments.length === 3 && $(arguments[0]).length && isNumber(arguments[1]) && isNumber(arguments[2])) 
        ;
    else
        return 0;

    // Clone embedded element
    $c = $(arguments[0]).clone();

    // Resize clone (replace width/height of all children who have them) 
    $c
        .attr('width', arguments[1])
        .attr('height', arguments[2])
        .children().each(function(){     
            $(this).attr('width') && $(this).attr('width', arguments[1]);
            $(this).attr('height') && $(this).attr('height', arguments[2]);
    })

    // Replace target with clone
    $(arguments[0]).replaceWith($c);
}

function isNumber(n){
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xjxVC/1